# empty_data not working for compound forms, or entity is not being instantiated (ArgumentCountError: too few arguments to function)

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I've got a `Company` that has many `Employee`s. In my form, I want the user to be able to dynamically add employees (easy enough). `EmployeeType` (an `AbstractType`) is compound, containing a first and last name. On form submission, Symfony doesn't seem to carry over the data from the form into the constructor for the "new" Employee. I get an erro

> ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function Employee::__construct() ... 0 passed in ... and exactly 3 expected

Showing and editing existing Employees works, so I'm confident my relationships, etc., are all correct.

Abbreviated code:

#### Company

```
class Company
{
    protected $employees;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->employees = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function addEmployee(Employee $employee)
    {
        if ($this->employees->contains($employee)) {
            return;
        }
        $this->employees->add($employee);
    }

    public function removeEmployee(Employee $employee)
    {
        if (!$this->employees->contains($employee)) {
            return;
        }
        $this->employees->removeElement($employee);
    }
}
```

#### Employee

```
class Employee
{
    // ... firstName and lastName properties...

    public function __construct(Company $company, $firstName, $lastName)
    {
        $this->company = $company;
        $this->company->addEmployee($this);
    }

    // ...getter and setter for firstName / lastName...
}
```

#### CompanyType

```
class CompanyType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('employees', CollectionType::class, [
            'entry_type' => EmployeeType::class,
            'allow_add' => true,
            'allow_delete' => false,
            'required' => false,
        ]);
        // ...other fields, some are CollectionType of TextTypes that work correctly...
    }
}
```

#### EmployeeType

```
class EmployeeType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('firstName')
            ->add('lastName');
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Employee::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

#### CompanyController

```
class CompanyController
{
    // Never mind that this is a show and not edit, etc.
    public function showAction()
    {
        // Assume $this->company is a new or existing Company
        $form = $this->createForm(CompanyType::class, $this->company);

        $form->handleRequest($this->request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $company = $form->getData();

            $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $entityManager->persist($company);
            $entityManager->flush();
        }

        // set flash message, redirect, etc.
    }

    // ...render view...
}
```

The above will work when modifying existing Employees, just not when creating new ones. Debugging from within the Symfony code, I can see that no data exists for the new employees, so it's trying to find a closure or definition for `empty_data` in `CompanyType`. I've tried this every which way (via `configureOptions`, and `empty_data` option when building the `CompanyType::buildForm` form), e.g. https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/use_empty_data.html. My gut tells me I don't even need to do this, because the form data should not be empty (I explicitly filled out the fields).

I tried using a model transformer as well. In that case, the transformation from the form (second function argument passed to `new CallbackTransformer`) isn't even hit.

The view properly sets name attributes when adding new employee fields, e.g. `form[employees][1][firstName]`, etc. That isn't the problem. It also sends the right data to the controller. I confirmed this by inspecting the form submission data via `CompanyType::onPreSubmit` (using an event listener).

I also have a `CollectionType` of `TextType`s for other things in `CompanyType`, those work fine. So the issue seems to be related to the fact that `EmployeeType` is compound (containing multiple fields).

Hopefully the above is enough to illustrate the problem. Any ideas?

UPDATE:

It seems the issue is there isn't an instantiation of `Employee` for Symfony to work with. Internally, each field gets passed to `Symfony\Component\Form\Form::submit()`. For existing employees, there is also an `Employee` passed in. For the new one, it's `null`. That explains why it's looking for `empty_data`, but I don't know why I can't get `empty_data` to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to define `empty_data` in the **compound form**, and not the `CollectionType` form.

My situation is a little weird, because I also need the instance of `Company` in my `EmployeeType`, as it must be passed to the constructor for `Employee`. I accomplished this by passing in the Company as form option into `configureOptions` (supplied by the controller), and then into `entry_options`. I don't know if this is best practice, but it works:

#### CompanyController

Make sure we pass in the Company instance, so it can be used in `EmployeeType` when building a new `Employee`:

```
$form = $this->createForm(CompanyType::class, $this->company, [
    // This is a form option, valid because it's in CompanyType::configureOptions()
    'company' => $this->company,
]);
```

#### CompanyType

```
class CompanyType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('employees', CollectionType::class, [
            // ...

            // Pass the Company instance to the EmployeeType.
            'entry_options' => [ 'company' => $options['company'] ],

            // This was also needed, apparently.
            'by_reference' => false,
        ]);
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            // Allows the controller to pass in a Company instance.
            'company' => null,
        ]);
    }
}
```

#### EmployeeType

Here we make sure `empty_data` properly builds an Employee from the form data.

```
class EmployeeType extends AbstractType
{
    private $company;

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('firstName')
            ->add('lastName');

        // A little weird to set a class property here, but we need the Company
        // instance in the 'empty_data' definition in configureOptions(),
        // at which point we otherwise wouldn't have access to the Company.
        $this->company = $options['company'];
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Employee::class,
            'empty_data' => function (FormInterface $form) use ($resolver) {
                return new Employee(
                    $this->company,
                    $form->get('firstName')->getData(),
                    $form->get('lastName')->getData(),
                );
            },
        ]);
    }
}
```

Viola! I can now add new employees.

Hope this helps other people!